# Rust Echo Command Implementation

Tags: beginner, strings, rust

I'm just starting out in Rust and I find the concept of ownership confusing so I wrote an implementation of the `echo` command. I would like to know if I could have set the initial value on the `echo` variable any better or just any general improvements.

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

    let mut echo: String;
    if let Some(string) = args.get(1) {
        echo = string.to_string();
    } else {
        return;
    }

    for arg in &args[2..] {
        echo.push(' ');
        echo.push_str(arg.as_str());
    }
    echo.push('\n');

    println!("{}", echo);
}
```

Comment: Actually this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36946085/7076153) cover almost all I could say.

Comment: @Stargateur Thanks a lot! I forgot to mention I didn't want to use any external crates so that works really well for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would not say I am any more proficient but I would make these changes if I wrote it.

- `skip(1)` first arg.
- `join(" ")` instead of iterate though args.

You do not need a mutable value.

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().skip(1).collect();

    if args.len() == 0 {
        println!("");
    } else {
        println!("{}", args.join(" "));
    }
}
```

I would do one more thing and send to `stdout` since your mimicking echo, but maybe much for this answer.

Comment: I didn't realize `env::Args` implemented the Iterator trait. It's definitely more elegant than my code, thanks!

Comment: Thank you. Honestly there are more cool tricks, I think you can get away with just join no 'if'.

Comment: @Genuinebyte *I didn't realize `env::Args` implemented the `Iterator` trait.* — where did you think `collect` was coming from?

Comment: What if you just omitted the `if args.len() == 0` branch completely? That would make the code even shorter.

Answer (score 6):

1. Use [`Iterator::skip`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.skip) instead of collecting the arguments into a `Vec` and then skipping over it.
2. This implementation should not have *any* allocation, whatsoever. Neither collecting the arguments or building an output string is needed.

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let mut args = env::args().skip(1);

    if let Some(arg) = args.next() {
        print!("{}", arg);

        for arg in args {
            print!(" {}", arg);
        }
    }

    println!();
}
```